Error : siunitx and \Trimspaces (expl3)
Could you help me move forward in resolving the problem described below ?
Thanks.

description

The error encountered during compilation appeared following the modifications
in the siunitx package, later than version 3.2.9.

extract from 'log' file (compilation carried out with siunitx 3.3.20)

(/opt/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-calculate/pst-calculate.sty
Package: pst-calculate 2019/01/24 v. 0.02(Herbert Voss) Support for caculations
 with floating point numbers.

(/opt/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty
Package: siunitx 2024-08-01 v3.3.20 A comprehensive (SI) units package
\l__siunitx_number_uncert_offset_int=\count610
\l__siunitx_number_exponent_fixed_int=\count611
\l__siunitx_number_min_decimal_int=\count612
\l__siunitx_number_min_integer_int=\count613
\l__siunitx_number_round_precision_int=\count614
\l__siunitx_number_lower_threshold_int=\count615
\l__siunitx_number_upper_threshold_int=\count616
\l__siunitx_number_group_first_int=\count617
\l__siunitx_number_group_size_int=\count618
\l__siunitx_number_group_minimum_int=\count619
\l__siunitx_angle_tmp_dim=\dimen424
\l__siunitx_angle_marker_box=\box165
\l__siunitx_angle_unit_box=\box166
\l__siunitx_compound_count_int=\count620

(/opt/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translations/translations.sty
Package: translations 2022/02/05 v1.12 internationalization of LaTeX2e packages
 (CN)

(/opt/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode is ignored in DVI mode.
))
\l__siunitx_table_tmp_box=\box167
\l__siunitx_table_tmp_dim=\dimen425
\l__siunitx_table_column_width_dim=\dimen426
\l__siunitx_table_integer_box=\box168
\l__siunitx_table_decimal_box=\box169
\l__siunitx_table_uncert_box=\box170
\l__siunitx_table_before_box=\box171
\l__siunitx_table_after_box=\box172
\l__siunitx_table_before_dim=\dimen427
\l__siunitx_table_carry_dim=\dimen428
\l__siunitx_unit_tmp_int=\count621
\l__siunitx_unit_position_int=\count622
\l__siunitx_unit_total_int=\count623

/opt/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty:8850: Argument of \T
rimSpaces has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.8850   }
          
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
/opt/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty:8850: Paragraph ende
d before \TrimSpaces was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.8850   }
          
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

/opt/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty:8876: Argument of \T
rimSpaces has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.8876   }
          
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
/opt/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty:8876: Paragraph ende
d before \TrimSpaces was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.8876   }
          
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

))


siunitx 3.3.20 (extract)

\ExpandArgs { Ne } \NewDocumentCommand \qtylist
  {
    O { }
    > { \SplitList { \exp_not:V \l__siunitx_list_tl } } m
    > { \TrimSpaces } m
  }% <-- **line 8850**
  {
    \mode_leave_vertical:
    \group_begin:
      \siunitx_unit_options_apply:n {#3}
      \keys_set:nn { siunitx } {#1}
      \siunitx_quantity_list:nn {#2} {#3}
    \group_end:
  }
\ExpandArgs { Ne } \NewDocumentCommand \numlist
  {
    O { }
    > { \SplitList { \exp_not:V \l__siunitx_list_tl } } m
  }
  {
    \mode_leave_vertical:
    \group_begin:
      \keys_set:nn { siunitx } {#1}
      \siunitx_number_list:nn {#2}
    \group_end:
  }
\ExpandArgs { Ne } \NewDocumentCommand \qtyproduct
  {
    O { }
    > { \SplitList { \exp_not:V \l__siunitx_product_tl } } m
    > { \TrimSpaces } m
  }% <-- **line 8876**
  {
    \mode_leave_vertical:
    \group_begin:
      \siunitx_unit_options_apply:n {#3}
      \keys_set:nn { siunitx } {#1}
      \siunitx_quantity_product:nn {#2} {#3}
    \group_end:
  }


siunitx 3.2.9 (extract)

\NewDocumentCommand \qtylist
  { O { } > { \SplitList { ; } } m > { \TrimSpaces } m }
  {
    \mode_leave_vertical:
    \group_begin:
      \siunitx_unit_options_apply:n {#3}
      \keys_set:nn { siunitx } {#1}
      \siunitx_quantity_list:nn {#2} {#3}
    \group_end:
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \numlist { O { } > { \SplitList { ; } } m }
  {
    \mode_leave_vertical:
    \group_begin:
      \keys_set:nn { siunitx } {#1}
      \siunitx_number_list:nn {#2}
    \group_end:
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \qtyproduct
  { O { } > { \SplitList { x } } m m }
  % 20240816V { O { } > { \SplitList { x } } m > { \TrimSpaces } m }
  {
    \mode_leave_vertical:
    \group_begin:
      \siunitx_unit_options_apply:n {#3}
      \keys_set:nn { siunitx } {#1}
      \siunitx_quantity_product:nn {#2} {#3}
    \group_end:
  }


LaTeX distribution

TeX Live 2024 regularly updated

comments

The siunitx package is not loaded directly, but by the pst-calculate package.
None of the 2 macros \qty and \qtyproduct are used directly in the code of the
compiled file.

welcome! can you provide the code for a minimal document we can compile to reproduce the problem?

My guess is you’ve somehow redefined \TrimSpaces. But we need a full example to help more

Thank you for your quick response.
At this time, I'm unable to simply reproduce the problem.
As I mentioned, it appeared after the update in siunitx package. And I don't know why these two commands are used because I don't call them explicitly in my code.

The error is coming during loading siunitx, not using it. So we need to see what you are doing before siunitx is loaded that is causing the issue.

add \show\TrimSpaces   to your preamble just before loading siunitx, what does it show

@JosephWright  \TrimSpace  becoming  non \protected and expanding in an e argument?

Thanks for your answers.
I've added \show\TrimSpaces.
> \TrimSpaces=macro:
#1->\begingroup \aftergroup \toks \aftergroup 0\aftergroup {\expandafter \trimb
 \expandafter \noexpand #1Q Q}\global \edef #1{\the \toks 0}.
l.30 \show\TrimSpaces


@davidcarlisle yes exactly

@EmmanuelPont that is the tokenizer package which is apparently incompatible with any latex release for the last few years.

@EmmanuelPont you could have shown an example document save me searching the entire texlive tree to see which package redefined \TrimSpaces :-)

SOLVED !
I have just tested by commenting the 'tokenizer' package which I
suspected neither the presence nor the usefulness of.  The compilation
no longer generated the error regarding 'TrimSpaces'.
Thank you very much for the time you devoted to my request.
PS: The personal organization developed to generate some of my
documents is akin to a gas factory. Some personal packages themselves
use an overly long list of generic packages. It's time to think about
simplifying this organization.

You should show your document as that will show where the error is,
The error suggests that you have something equivalent to
\documentclass{article}
\def\TrimSpaces#1{}
\usepackage{pst-calculate}


\begin{document}

\end{document}

or
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokenizer}
\usepackage{pst-calculate}


\begin{document}

\end{document}

which produce
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
! Argument of \TrimSpaces has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.8850   }
          
?

But it is impossible to say what has redefined \TrimSpaces or what it has beeen defined to do, given the information posted.
